# How can I get involved in ROS community?

Tags: ros, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm just starting to learn ROS.
Is there anything I can do to help ROS while I'm learning it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9073/how-can-i-get-involved-in-ros-community?/) by [Alex Bravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/27/alex-bravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 901 on 2011-02-15

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a wiki page with an overview of ways to contribute.  http://www.ros.org/wiki/Get%20Involved

I highly recommend running through a good number of the tutorials to start.  We've worked hard to try to give coverage of the core of the system.  You can get started at http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/StartGuide

---

Originally posted by [Tully](https://answers.ros.org/users/7/tully/) with karma: 1145 on 2011-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5